# Intuitively, why does the spectral gap control the speed of convergence to equilibrium.

Tags: markov-chains, spectral-theory, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators, stationary-processes

Is there an intuitive way to understand the following principle :

Given a Markov Process $X_t$ with generator $L$, why does the spectral gap of $L$ control the speed of convergence to equilibrium for $X_t$.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but i think it would be better if you would provide some additional context. For example, you could include (a reference to) the theorem stating the relationship between the spectral gap of $L$ and the rate of convergence of $X$ to a stationary distribution.

Comment: If you rewrite the generator into a sum of its eigen "quasi-generators" and eigenvalues (= the spectrum) then each summand represents itself a partial process that "expires" with the rate of its eigenvalue. There is always one eigenvalue = 1 and its "generator" is the process to directly go to the equilibrium. The next eigenvalue closest to one (= the spectral gap) represents the slowest non-vanishing process, all others are faster to disappear. Hence the spectral gap determines the dominant non-static process and once this is gone you are at equilibrium.

Comment: @jhp Could you please elaborate as an answer :-)

Comment: Actually, you need to be careful. The gap is relevant when you already are at equilibrium, it's the correlation time. However, to get to equilibrium from a given distribution you are more interested in the mixing time which can be orders of magnitude longer (e.g. Ehrenfest's urn).